# How to set IntelliJ IDEA to treat parameters as-if they were annotated with @Nullable?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Is it possible to setup IntelliJ IDEA to treat code like this:

```
private void myMethod(final String item) {
    ...
}
```

as if it were actually

```
private void myMethod(final @Nullable String item) {
    ...
}
```

So that I would be forced to add @NotNull/@NonNull, if I really mean it?

**Solution:**
[image: Where to find the correct checkbox...]

Comment: Dude, it's literally one word. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/nullable-and-notnull-annotations.html

Comment: Use indentation, not backticks, for code blocks.

Comment: Imagine a legacy code, you do not want to add @Nullable into each existing method...

Comment: @chrylis Thank you, look much better :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a setting in Settings | Inspections | Constant Conditions & Exceptions to treat non-annotated members and parameters as nullable, although it'd apply also to methods and fields.

Comment: That's it! Thank you.